# How to auto-sort a table in Numbers?

Tags: macos, ipad, numbers, sort

I'm trying to get Numbers to "auto" sort a table when data is entered into a different table.

It's for a simple round robin tennis tournament, where points are accumulated each round, and I'd like to have the players ranked after each round based on Total Points.

I've used RANK and it's working perfectly to calculate the results, however, the ranking table doesn't automatically sort via the Rank Column when a new value is added in the main table on the left.

This spreadsheet is being used on an iPad and the games are just 12 minutes long. So, it's not practical to have the players having to sort the column every time.

[image: Calculating the Total Points and Ranking them]

Is there a formula or trigger / procedure I can use that will monitor the Rank column and sort it when new data is entered on the left?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't fully automate the re-sorting process in Numbers. However, you might be able to make the overall process a bit more convenient by automating the transfer of `Total Points` from the table on the left to the table on the right using a function such as `XLOOKUP`, if you are not already doing so and if the list of players does not change frequently.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. The Total Points gets transferred immediately using the current formula. It updates any time a change is made in any of the Rounds (R1 through to R10). I just wish that I could use a formula to "listen" to the Total Points Column on the right hand Table and then apply the sorting via Rank.